# Publish .aar file with javadocs attached on artifactory repo

Tags: android, maven, gradle, artifactory, aar

I'm trying to publish an AAR with javadoc file to my maven repo through artifactory gradle puglin.

The aar file is doing uploaded with success, but i the javadoc don't. Which script can i use to upload my javadocs?.

This is my build.gradle code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

def packageName = 'br.com.lexsis.libtest'
def libraryVersion = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        aar(MavenPublication) {
            groupId packageName
            version = libraryVersion
            artifactId project.getName()

            // Tell maven to prepare the generated "*.aar" file for publishing
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.getName()}-release.aar")

            pom.withXml {
                def dependencies = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                configurations.getByName("_releaseCompile").getResolvedConfiguration().getFirstLevelModuleDependencies().each {
                    def dependency = dependencies.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependency.appendNode('groupId', it.moduleGroup)
                    dependency.appendNode('artifactId', it.moduleName)
                    dependency.appendNode('version', it.moduleVersion)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
    publish {
        repository {
            // The Artifactory repository key to publish to
            repoKey = libraryVersion.endsWith('SNAPSHOT') ? 'libs-snapshot-local' : 'libs-release-local'

            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
        defaults {
            // Tell the Artifactory Plugin which artifacts should be published to Artifactory.
            publications('aar')
            publishArtifacts = true

            // Properties to be attached to the published artifacts.
            properties = ['qa.level': 'basic', 'dev.team': 'core']
            // Publish generated POM files to Artifactory (true by default)
            publishPom = true
        }
    }
}

task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
}

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
}

artifacts {
    archives androidSourcesJar
    archives androidJavadocsJar
}
```

Comment: This link might help: http://central.sonatype.org/pages/gradle.html. I was able to get it all uploaded by following the instructions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your publication only includes the aar file:

`artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.getName()}-release.aar")`

Add another artifact - the output of the `androidJavadocsJar` task:

`artifact androidJavadocsJar`

Repeat for sources jar, if you want.

Comment: sorry, I'm begginer on groovy and gradle. So, What i need to do is add two more lines: artifact androidJavadocsJar AND artifact androidJavadocSources ?

Comment: Yes, in the publication

Comment: Of course ) I'd author suggest changing the first artifact to be a task name as well, not a file name. Also, you don't need the artifacts block.

Comment: Do you know which task can I use instead of file name?

Comment: @JBaruch I have the same problem. Can please explain how to add another artifact for the output of the androidJavadocJar

Answer (score 7):

This works for me.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

def packageName = 'br.com.lexsis.libtest'
def libraryVersion = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        aar(MavenPublication) {
            groupId packageName
            version = libraryVersion
            artifactId project.getName()

            // Tell maven to prepare the generated "*.aar" file for publishing
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.getName()}-release.aar")
            artifact androidJavadocsJar

            pom.withXml {
                def dependencies = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                configurations.getByName("_releaseCompile").getResolvedConfiguration().getFirstLevelModuleDependencies().each {
                    def dependency = dependencies.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependency.appendNode('groupId', it.moduleGroup)
                    dependency.appendNode('artifactId', it.moduleName)
                    dependency.appendNode('version', it.moduleVersion)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
    publish {
        repository {
            // The Artifactory repository key to publish to
            repoKey = libraryVersion.endsWith('SNAPSHOT') ? 'libs-snapshot-local' : 'libs-release-local'

            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
        defaults {
            // Tell the Artifactory Plugin which artifacts should be published to Artifactory.
            publications('aar')
            publishArtifacts = true

            // Properties to be attached to the published artifacts.
            properties = ['qa.level': 'basic', 'dev.team': 'core']
            // Publish generated POM files to Artifactory (true by default)
            publishPom = true
        }
    }
}

task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
}

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
}

artifacts {
    archives androidSourcesJar
    archives androidJavadocsJar
}
```

Comment: The `artifacts { ... }` block at the root level is not required since you're using the `maven-publish` plugin and you could add an `artifact androidSourcesJar` entry in the `aar(MavenPublication) { ... }` block in order to publish the sources as well as the Javadoc and the aar file.

Answer (score 0):

with latest versions of Gradle, you don`t need to define the tasks to generate javadocs or sources jar,
just add the following code to the java block in your project

```
java {
    sourceCompatibility = javaVersion
    targetCompatibility = javaVersion

    withSourcesJar()
    withJavadocJar()
}
```

then in the artifactory, add the artifact with the path of sources.jar file and change his classifier

```
    publishing {
    publications {
        "aar"(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId = variant
            groupId = "testId"
            version = versioning

            artifact("$buildDir/libs/yourJarFile.jar")
            artifact("$buildDir/libs/yourJarFile-sources.jar"){
                classifier = 'sources'
            }

        }
    }
}
```