# Android Studio aar obfuscated library publishing with javadoc

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, javadoc, artifactory

I have published Android libraries in a private Artifactory [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32339238/publish-aar-file-with-javadocs-attached-on-artifactory-repo).
Javadoc is generated and published as a jar file together with the aar library to artifactory.

However, when using the library from another Android Studio project, the javadoc is not automatically showing in Android Studio quick documentation.
Upon a little more trial and errors, it seems that javadoc will be shown in the quick documentation of Android Studio if the library is **not** obfuscated during publishing

How can I go about publishing my obfuscated library and show javadoc without additional configuration in Android Studio for library users?

[Edit]
The published library files are:
aar, javadoc.jar, sources.jar, pom file

Currently, the sources.jar allows developers to reverse engineer the un-obfuscated source code, but still does not provide the javadoc for the library.

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue? I am struggling with the same thing and so far couldn't find a solution.

Comment: @Marty I have not managed to find an answer to this. At this point, I am still refering the developers to a separated HTML Javadocs page.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am doing the same thing and as it seems there is no better way so far :(

Answer (score 2):

You need to do 'sources' release as well. 
If i understand you correctly, you want the developer which uses your aar to be able to see the documentation of the class with your notes.

In your gradle file, create a 'source' job like so :

```
task javadocTask(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

task sourcesTask(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource 
    //Or exact project path if you don't have sourceSets : from "YOUR_PROJECT/src/main/java"
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesTask
    archives javadocTask
}
```

Comment: Thats the thing... all the documentations are in the sources and the javadocs is external(obviously you can open it, but it'll be manually and not through code inspection)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to ensure that you are not obfuscating public APIs of your library.

By default the javadoc for a library is not downloaded until specified explicitly. You need to put following config in application's main build.gradle

```
idea {
  module {
    downloadJavadoc = true
   }
}
```

Sync project with gradle file by clicking on Sync Now link from top right or by clicking following icon:
[Sync Project with gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmZV2.png)

Android studio will download the javadoc and link it with your API appropriately.

If the javadoc is still not visible then try to invalidate cache and restart android studio from: File > Invalidate Caches/ Restart > Invalidate and Restart.