# How to attach sources of an AAR file with maven-publish gradle plugin?

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I publish an AAR to another part of my team that checks out only this AAR, not the source code.

I would like to provide them with the source code, seamlessly (with Ctrl + Click on class or Ctrl + B to get on the source code directly inside Android Studio).

As far as I understand, it's only possible with .jar archives, not .aar.

Here's the maven-publish configuration file. I can publish the archives (debug, "release" and sources) to the maven. I can get the debug dependency ("xxx-debug.aar"). I can download manually the sources ("xxx-sources.jar") and link them via "Choose sources..." in Android Studio. But the linking isn't automatic like any other decent library (Retrofit or OkHttp comes to mind) :

```
// MAVEN PUBLICATION

apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier "sources"
}

publishing {

    group = 'foo.bar.rootpackage'
    version = "foobar1.0"

    publications {

        aar(MavenPublication) {

            println("Maven publish: package name is ${aarName}")

            groupId group
            artifactId sdkModuleName
            version version

            artifact(sourceJar)

            def debugAar = "$buildDir/outputs/aar/${aarName}-debug.aar"
            if (new File(debugAar).exists()) {
                artifact(debugAar) {
                    classifier 'debug'
                    extension 'aar'
                }
            }

            def releaseAar = "$buildDir/outputs/aar/${aarName}-release.aar"
            if (new File(releaseAar).exists()) {
                artifact(releaseAar) {
                    extension 'aar'
                }
            }

            //The publication doesn't know about our dependencies, so we have to manually add them to the pom
            pom.withXml {
                def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')

                def compileTimeDependencies = configurations.api.allDependencies +
                        configurations.implementation.allDependencies +
                        configurations.releaseImplementation.allDependencies

                appendDependencies(compileTimeDependencies, dependenciesNode)
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            // PRIVATE MAVEN STUFF
        }
    }
}

ext {
    appendDependencies = { Set<Dependency> compileTimeDependencies, dependenciesNode ->

        compileTimeDependencies.each {
            def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
            dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
            dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
            dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)

            if (!it.excludeRules.isEmpty()) {
                def exclusionsNode = dependencyNode.appendNode('exclusions')
                it.excludeRules.each { rule ->
                    def exclusionNode = exclusionsNode.appendNode('exclusion')
                    exclusionNode.appendNode('groupId', rule.group)
                    exclusionNode.appendNode('artifactId', rule.module ?: '*')
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the build.gradle of the other project needing this dependency, I implement the dependency like that :

```
    debugApi("foo.bar.rootpackage:core:$foobar1.0:debug@aar") {
        transitive = true
    }
    releaseApi("foo.bar.rootpackage:core:$foobar1.0@aar") {
        transitive = true
    }
```

Project builds, but no "automatic link" with the sources.

How to fix ?

Comment: See "Publish .aar file with javadocs attached on artifactory repo"
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32339238/publish-aar-file-with-javadocs-attached-on-artifactory-repo

Answer (score 0):

Use [android-maven-publish](https://github.com/wupdigital/android-maven-publish). Linking the sources package should happen in the generated POM.

Comment: Thanks for the link but it no longer works with 5.0+ (or upcoming 6.0+ for that matter)

Comment: Plugin version `3.6.2` should work with Gradle `4.8`. For Gradle `5.0` you either have to use [afterEvaluate](https://github.com/wupdigital/android-maven-publish/issues/30) - or `org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.LazyPublishArtifact`.

Answer (score 0):

in my case using aar, i should include `javadocJar` artifact as well for it to be automatically linked.

you can try something similar to this :

```
...
task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}
    
task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

publishing {

    ...

    publications {

        aar(MavenPublication) {
            artifact(sourceJar)
            artifact(javadocJar)
            ...
```

Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28969412)